# Azure Functions - Azure Iot hub not triggering Functions

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

My function is never trigger.

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccounttesti9ad4;AccountKey=XXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureEventHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://iothub-ns-iothub-tes-10126268-5c2cc2a05d.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=YYY;EntityPath=iothub-test-001"
  }
}
```

```cs
namespace functionapp2
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //iothub-test-001
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("iothub-test-001", Connection = "AzureEventHubConnectionString")]EventData message, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}");
        }
    }
}
```

For sending message to IotHub I use [this script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios/provision_symmetric_key.py)

Thanks in advance to those who can enlighten me!

Comment: I managed to make it work in Typescript :) I must have made a wrong manipulation in C# !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, surely a bad manipulation.  I deleted and started again in C# (and typescript) and it works!
Update : I have just forgotten to put AzureEventHubConnectionString variable in the configuration of my Azure Function !

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `EventHubTrigger` attribute instead of `IoTHubTrigger` attribute and follow the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it does not work.